# Что хуже: говнарь, говнюк или гадёныш?

Tags: семантика

Ну, вопрос в заголовке. Что хуже, очевидно, == "что обиднее".

Comment: Только человек с таким псевдонимом мог задать такой вопрос...

Comment: Только человек с таким псевдонимом мог дать такой комментарий...

Comment: @stopkran, и в самом деле: ну зачем такие крайности? Помнится, в молодые годы я пришёл как приглашённый на занятие литературного кружка. Юноши и девушки читали свои стихи - о любви, о весне, о солнышке. "Прочитайте и Вы свои", - обратились ко мне. И я прочитал: о том, как меня дождливой осенью будут хоронить, лягушки будут прыгать по крышке гроба, а потом их закопают вместе со мною.  "Пройдут года. Травою зарастёт Могильный холм, моя обитель в бездне, От времени и влаги крест сгниёт, И память обо мне навек исчезнет", - с тихой патетикой закончил я. Все молчали. А Вам мы со @Злата ответили.

Comment: Очень хороший рассказ от слов "Помнится, в молодые годы ..." и до слов "Все молчали.".

Comment: Так и хочется ответить: "В сортах д...ма не разбираюсь"))) Все одинаково мерзко.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос действительно странный... С чего бы такие исследования проводить?!
Но дело даже не в этом, или не только в этом. Что за странный ряд? 
Первого не слышал вообще, второе и третье - из разных плоскостей. А потому и сравнивать нельзя. Ну это помимо того, что тут вообще любая оценка субъективна.